# Way to capture the exec command result which can be used later in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am running wildfly elytron-tool.sh to mask the password. It is done after the wildfly directory is installed in my node server which is done previous to this step. I want to capture that masked password which is returned from the exec command which can be used later.
How to achieve that?

```
class classname{
    exec { '${jboss_home}/bin/elytron-tool.sh mask --salt=12345678 --iteration=256 --secret=':
       command => "${jboss_home}/bin/elytron-tool.sh mask --salt=12345678 --iteration=256 --secret=password",
       user    => $owner,
       path    => $path,
      } 
}
```

Comment: Set [`logoutput`](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/exec#exec-attribute-logoutput) to `true` and have a look at [PuppetDB](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/). Obviously storing _this_ particular output is not really wise. Today you may craft something with [deferred functions](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/deferred_functions). I’ve never seriously used them so I can’t give you an answer proper.